# Same Structured Data on multiple pages?

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, structured-data

I was certain about this at first, but the more I think about it the more uncertain I get.

The site is offering 28 educations, and each education is X times a year. There are three different education-related pages on the site:

- An overview page of the different educations.
- A page for each education.
- A calendar page for all upcoming occasions/educations (presented one month at a time).

I don't want the overview page and the calendar page to compete against each other. If that's the case, the overview page is most important.

Should I add Rich Snippets (a.k.a. Structured Data) on all three pages?

Comment: This is tagged SEO, but rich snippets don't generally help with SEO.  There are only a few snippets (like reviews) that will make your site appear different in the search results.   Even those don't improve rankings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Stephen. I know that Rich Snippets won't affect rankings, this is is only for the appearence in the search results. Events do appear in the results: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/events

Answer (score 1):

I think, your first (overview page of the different educations) and third (calendar page) page should be the same, namely the homepage. According to this i would add it on two kinds of pages:

- events markup for all upcoming events for the month overview, on the homepage
- event markup with upcoming dates on each singular education page

Answer (score 0):

Google's John Mueller recently [weighed in on this](https://youtu.be/DSKD6bOMZSc?t=11m17s):

> In general, the structured data on a website or on a page
>   should be specific to that particular page.
>   So it shouldn't be something where you kind of say, well,
>   this is a review of our business in general,
>   and therefore, we'll put it on all of the pages

So you should only mark up a piece of structured data on one page, and it should be on the page that covers that as the main topic of the page.